# How to pivot/transfom a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have the following dataframe:

```
 df1 :
     Num   B1   B2   B3   B4 
  0  P1    V1   V2  NaN  NaN
  1  P2    V1  NaN   V2  NaN
  2  P3   NaN   V2  NaN   V1
```

And I want to transform/create an other dataframe like this :

```
 df2 :
          P1   P2   P3
  0  V1   B1   B1   B4
  1  V2   B2   B3   B2
```

Could you help me to do this tranformation ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can first `melt` and then `pivot`:

```
print (df.melt(id_vars="Num").dropna().pivot("value", "Num", "variable"))

Num    P1  P2  P3
value            
V1     B1  B1  B4
V2     B2  B3  B2
```